# pass a variable between two methods

Tags: iphone, string, variables

I was trying to pass a variable of type NSString from a method to another. what I have done is:

```
-(void)some{
NSString *lat = something
NSString *longt = somethingElse
[self test:lat:longt];
}
```

and then

```
- (IBAction)test:(NSString *)lat:(NSString *)longt{
doSomeThing
}
```

But my problem is that now the IBAction button is activated without my press.

how do I run the method IBAction under my control

Comment: what do you mean by button is activated without my press?

Comment: means that the action is executed without me press the button

Comment: You have the answers below, but **don't name the method `test::`**.  Name it something like `testWithLatitude:longitude:` or, more completely, `-(void)testWithLatitude:(NSString*)aLat longitude:(NSString*)aLong;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test method should not be an `IBAction`.  Instead do this:

```
- (void)test:(NSString *)lat:(NSString *)longt{
    //doSomeThing
}

-(IBAction)myAction:(id)sender
{
    //call test from here
    [self some];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you cannot pass arbitrary parameters through an IBAction, you can either pass the control sending the action or nothing:

```
-(IBAction)action:(id)sender;
or
-(IBAction)action;
```

Comment: ok I can not pass the variable using this solution, then how do I pass variables from void to IBAction?

Comment: I think you are not really understanding some of the basics of objective C and/or UIKit. I would suggest reading the documentation.

Comment: You do not _pass_ them. You should declare some ivars for this purpose. And, yes, read the docs :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use void as returm type of method not ibaction. If u need it for some action thn call it from there.

Answer (score -1):

use

```
- (void) test:(NSString *)lat:(NSString *)longt
```

instead of

```
- (IBAction)test:(NSString *)lat:(NSString *)longt
```